# onreadystatechange に対して addEventListener を使わないのはなぜか

Tags: javascript, ajax

`readystatechange` はイベントなのだから `addEventListener` を使って登録できると思うんですが、大抵のAjaxサンプルでは `onreadystatechange` に代入する方法をとってると思います。

なにか避ける理由でもあるんでしょうか。ちょっと長いから？

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/file", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if( this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
  if( this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
xhr.send("");
```

Comment: `addEventListener` を持たないような古いブラウザ（例えばIE8以前)で使えないからですかね。

Comment: 既存のイベントハンドラを上書きするおそれがある場合には`addEventListener`を使って、XHRにはその心配がないからでは。

Answer (score 2):

（現在はどうか分かりませんが、）addEventListenerの方はOperaでは動かないみたいですね。
W3Cの仕様でいえばreadystatechangeを発火しないとダメなんですが、それに従っていないようです。

ズバリな質問がありました ↓

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971259/readystatechange-using-addeventlistener-versus-old-style-property